# Node Packages vs Browser ones

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

For example, packages like [highlight.js](http://highlightjs.org/) works in node just like in browser. What is considered best practice/faster/ideal?

In this case, highlight.js beautifies a `<code>` tag with color schemes. Example: In a blog where you use it, there are 2 cases:

- Fetch post, show post to user and let the browser/client version
  beautify the code, **or**
- Fetch post, pass the contents to the highlight
  node function, and show the entire results to the user.

My concerns:

- Free up server stress. Show website earlier, since it doesn't need to
  parse any data.
- Avoid browser incompatibility (not a big deal tbh).
- Save some static requests if not using CDN. Maybe faster?

I don't know what else I'm missing or what should be considered. What do you think?

PD: Every day more packages are browser/node compatible, but I think this is the best example I can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to that question can vary, but I would prefer to do it on the client side. Here are some pros and cons of the client-side route:

- **PRO**: The one you mentioned, server load reduced. Remember, you're paying for your server and your client is paying for the connection (sometimes figuratively, as in wait time). If you process server-side, you pay more; if you process client-side, the client pays more. I would let the client pay!
- **CON**: On the other hand, the syntax highlighting will load faster if you process server-side, because you can process once then cache for all subsequent clients.
- **CON**: Browser incompatibility, like you said.
- **PRO**: Semantics. You're augumenting highlihgting on top of the raw data, rather than having the raw data strung up between `<span>`s. Think about non-JS machines trying to process your page.